# Classification of boundary points of convex sets in $R^n$

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $P\neq R^n$ be a convex set containing an $R^n$ neighborhood of $0$. Then $x\in\partial P\iff (\lbrace tx: 0\leq t < 1\rbrace\subset P^\circ)\wedge(x\not\in P^\circ)$

(incomplete)**Proof:** ($\Leftarrow$) This direction is easy. Select a sequence $\lbrace t_n\rbrace \to 1$ so that $\lbrace t_n x\rbrace\to x$. This gives that $x$ is a point of closure of $P^\circ$, and by assumption it is not in $P^\circ$. Thus $x\in\partial P$.

($\Rightarrow$) This direction I am having trouble with. $x\notin P^\circ$ comes for free. I know that $\lbrace t\geq0 : tx\in P^\circ\rbrace$ is an interval by convexity and by the fact that $P^\circ$ contains $0$.

I believe now I need to use some properties of $R^n$ to nail this down, but the cases are getting very complicated. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider a ball $B$ of radius $\varepsilon$ with center $0$ which is contained in $P^°$. This exists by the assumption that $P$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$.

For given $x_0\in \partial P$ consider the set $C_{x_0,B}:=\{tx_0+ (1-t)y:y\in B, 0\le t<1\}$, which is a subset of $P$ (by convexity, it's a cone with base $B$ and vertex $x_0$ with $x_0$ removed).

This set $C_{x_0,B}$ is a neighbourhood of $\{tx_0:0\le t < 1\}$ and this latter set consists of interior point of $C_{x_0,B}$, and consequently of interior points of $P$ (I leave it to you to show this. It's, however, not difficult to see that for each point $p$ along the open line segment from $0$ to $x_0$ there is a whole ball around $p$ which is contained in $C_{x_0,B}$).

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: However, I've been thinking about it. You argue that $C_{x_0,B}$ is a subset of $P$. You do not have sufficient evidence to make this claim, as we do not know that $x_0$ is in $P$, hence we may not apply the convexity property. However, if $P$ were closed this would be fine. If $P$ isn't closed, we would have to know that $(\overline{P})^\circ=P^\circ$. In general, this isn't true. But I believe it is so for convex sets. I have a hunch that we need Hahn-Banach in order to prove this.